# Merging two SQLite databases which both have junction tables

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I got two SQLite databases which both have junction tables to describe the *one-to-many* relationship. Now these two DB need to be merged into a single one with some kind of import/export mechanism and still keep the relationships.

I tried to dump **DB2** with `.dump` and then load it back in **DB1** with `.read`, but always got `PRIMARY KEY must be unique` warnings.

Is there any best practice to handle this kind of situation?

Preferred not to use `attach` to avoid extra complexity.

---

### DB1

#### Fruit

```
--------------
| id | name  |
--------------
| 1  | Apple |
| 2  | Lemon |
| 3  | Kiwi  |
--------------
```

#### Juice

```
----------------
| id | name    |
----------------
| 1  | Juice A |
| 2  | Juice B |
----------------
```

#### Recipe (Junction Table)

```
----------------------------
| id | juice_id | fruit_id |
----------------------------
| 1  | 1        | 1        |
| 2  | 1        | 2        |
| 3  | 2        | 1        |
| 4  | 2        | 3        |
----------------------------
```

---

### DB2

#### Fruit

```
---------------
| id | name   |
---------------
| 1  | Kiwi   |
| 2  | Lemon  |
| 3  | Apple  |
| 4  | Orange |
---------------
```

#### Juice

```
----------------
| id | name    |
----------------
| 1  | Juice C |
| 2  | Juice D |
----------------
```

#### Recipe (Junction Table)

```
----------------------------
| id | juice_id | fruit_id |
----------------------------
| 1  | 1        | 1        |
| 2  | 1        | 3        |
| 3  | 2        | 2        |
| 4  | 2        | 4        |
----------------------------
```

Comment: Are the `name`s unique, and should they stay unique after the merge?

Comment: Would you be willing to use `ATTACH` if it resulted in *less* complexity?

Comment: `name` could be unique or not, the important thing is to keep the junction table's relationship and fix primary key conflict problem. Using `attach` to me is like to operate two sub-databases rather then a single one. Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: So you would be okay with two different fruits named "Apple"?

Comment: Yes, it's okay with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about duplicates, you could get the maximum ID from DB1, and add it to every ID in DB2.
However, you said that `name` could be unique, so let's do this right.

I'm assuming that all `id` columns are `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, i.e., autoincrementing.

Open DB1, and attach DB2:

```
ATTACH '...' AS db2;
```

Copy over all fruits and juices that do not yet exist in DB1 (these get new IDs):

```
INSERT INTO Fruit(name)
SELECT name
FROM db2.Fruit
WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT name
                   FROM Fruit);
INSERT INTO Juice(name)
SELECT name
FROM db2.Juice
WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT name
                   FROM Juice);
```

Now copy over the recipes, while looking up the new ID values through the corresponding name:

```
INSERT INTO Recipe(juice_id, fruit_id)
SELECT (SELECT id
        FROM Juice
        WHERE name = (SELECT name
                      FROM db2.Juice
                      WHERE id = Recipe2.juice_id)),
       (SELECT id
        FROM Fruit
        WHERE name = (SELECT name
                      FROM db2.Fruit
                      WHERE id = Recipe2.fruit_id))
FROM db2.Recipe AS Recipe2;
```

Comment: what if the Fruit's order are different in `DB1` and `DB2`, as the example in the original question?

Comment: Then the IDs change. (Which is the entire purpose of those subqueries.)